# Setting instance variable in another object in Xcode

Tags: objective-c, xcode5, instance-variables

I am trying to write an Xcode OS X app that allows double clicking on an image well's image to open another, larger, window of the image in the image well. The problem is that I cannot seem to transfer the image variable to the new window.

I have created a sub class of `NSImageView` called cardImageView which is bound to the image well of the main window. All this class does is handle the mouse up event and initiate the new window to hold the image like this:

```
- (void)mouseUp:(NSEvent *)theEvent
{
    if ([theEvent clickCount] == 2) {
        NSLog(@"double click in NS image cell");
        if (!self.cardImageViewController) {
            self.cardImageViewController = [[cardImageViewerWindowController alloc]init];
            self.cardImageViewController.cardImage.objectValue = self.cardImageViewImage;
            NSLog(@"ib account = %@",self.IBAccount);

        self.cardImageViewController.ibAccount = self.IBAccount;


    }
    [self.cardImageViewController showWindow:nil];

}
}
```

cardImageViewImage and `IBAccount` are both in the public API of the class cardImageView as follows:

```
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface cardImageView : NSImageView

@property (strong) NSImageCell *cardImageViewImage;
@property (strong) NSString *IBAccount;

@end
```

The problem is that both variables contain null when this class is run even though they are being set within my main window controller like this:

```
 if (!self.cardImageView) {
            self.cardImageView = [[cardImageView alloc]init];
        }
        self.cardImageView.cardImageViewImage = self.whosAccount.cardImage;
        self.cardImageView.IBAccount = self.whosAccount.ibAccount;
```

cardImageView is designated in the private API of the main window controller as follows:

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet cardImageView *cardImageView;
```

These lines are part of a method which get called whenever the image changes in the main window image well. I know that both `self.whosAccount.cardImage` and `self.whosAccount.ibAccount` contain data as they are used to populate the main window.

I don't understand why when I set `self.cardImageView.cardImageViewImage` and `self.cardImageView.IBAccount` in the main window controller they are not able to be referenced in the  cardImageView class.

Any help would be appreciated as I am clearly doing something wrong.

Comment: Does the `CardImageViewController` create the `cardImage` in its `init` method?  If not `self.cardImageViewController.cardImage.objectValue = ...;` will be referencing a `nil` object.

Comment: trojanfoe, the programs breaks down before it can get to that part. In the sub class cardImageView which holds the mouseup method, self.cardImageViewImage and self.IBAccount both are null. The NSLog statement in that method confirms that self.IBAccount is null. I don't understand why that should be the case.

Comment: I have been doing some further investigation as to what is happening and if I call a method in `cardImageView` immediately after they are set in the main window controller, both `self.cardImageViewImage` and `self.IBAccount` are both set. It appears that when the `mouseUp` method is called from the mouse event the instance variables are not set. Has anyone come across this before?